# Replace special strings in python

Tags: python, string, replace

How can I use a replace to eliminate the string: "b'\n"?

Due to backslash being a special character, I have had some problems with it.

Comment: Please give a [mcve] to illustrate the specific problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the replace method.

```
>>> # The 'r' prefix indicates it is a raw string
>>> string = r"b'\n" 
>>> print(string.replace(r"b'\n'", ""))
>>> 
>>> # It will replace the pattern you wanted to a empty string
```

Hope this helps

References:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#text-sequence-type-str

Answer (score 1):

Use a [regular expression](https://www.regular-expressions.info/python.html) with the special character `\\` to catch a backslash :

```py
from re import sub

test_string = "ab'\ncdef"
sub(pattern = "b'\\n", repl = " - found it - ", string = test_string)

>>> 'a - found it - cdef'
```

Comment: I would like to do the same but in a column of a dataframe.